# Transposing a Numpy Array on a slice

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have a 2d array and I am trying to create a 3d array in which each each row is a repeated element, in this case 9 times, of the original array. I think this involves transposing on some kind of a np slice.... my numpy skills are a bit rough...

Here is an example:

input:

```
an_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
a = an_array.reshape(3,2)
a

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

        [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],

        [[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]])
```

This was my idea, but it does not quite give the desired output. The rows are in the wrong order plus the shape is (2,3,9) instead of (3,2,9), which is an easy issue to resolve, but anyway, I was wondering if there might be quick way to do this?

```
new = np.transpose([a[:]]*9)
new

array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reshape` and using broadcasting

```
a_out = a.reshape(3,-1,1) * np.ones(9)

Out[40]:
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]],

       [[3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.]],

       [[5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
        [6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.]]])
```

Or

```
a_out = np.broadcast_to(np.reshape(a, (3,-1,1)), (3,2,9))

Out[43]:
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [102]: arr = np.arange(1,7).reshape(3,2)
In [103]: arr
Out[103]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

You didn't show the middle step, but I assume its:

```
In [104]: arr.repeat(4)
Out[104]: 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6,
       6, 6])
In [105]: arr.repeat(4).reshape(3,2,4)
Out[105]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6]]])
```

transpose of that is easy, and relatively cheap (in numpy)

```
In [106]: arr.repeat(4).reshape(3,2,4).transpose(1,0,2)
Out[106]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 3, 3, 3],
        [5, 5, 5, 5]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4],
        [6, 6, 6, 6]]])
```

`repeat` lets you specify the axis.  You want to expand on a new last axis, but you also want a (2,3) instead of `(3,2), so start with transpose

```
In [4]: arr.T[:,:,None]
Out[4]: 
array([[[1],
        [3],
        [5]],

       [[2],
        [4],
        [6]]])
In [5]: arr.T[:,:,None].repeat(4,axis=2)
Out[5]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 3, 3, 3],
        [5, 5, 5, 5]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4],
        [6, 6, 6, 6]]])
```

or for the (3,2,n) directly:

```
In [9]: arr[:,:,None].repeat(4,axis=2)
Out[9]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6]]])
```

All these manipulations are relatively cheap so they can be mixed and matched as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try transposing the vstack and then reshape

```
a = np.transpose([np.vstack(an_array)]*9)
a.reshape(3,2,9)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Damn browliv great job answering that

Comment: Hi @Dhruv and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not an answer to the question. Looks like you wanted to do comment or something like that. Anyway, I recommend you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer